# Angularjs failing to enter a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, mvvm

I seem to be having an issue with Angularjs using 'NgRoute' to navigate to a page. I have 3 other pages with controllers and they work absolutely fine, however when trying to go the the Dashboard page it only loads the view and not the controller.

**AngularJS App**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when("/dashboard", {
        contoller: "dashboardController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/dashboard.html",
    })

    $routeProvider.when("/machines", {
        controller: "machineController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/machines.html",
    })

    $routeProvider.when("/departments", {
        controller: "departmentController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/departments.html",
    })

    $routeProvider.when("/users", {
        controller: "userController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/users.html",
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/dashboard" });
});
```

**Controller**

```
'use strict';
app.controller('dashboardController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Page', function ($scope, $http, Page) {
    Page.setTitle('Dashboard');

}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="app">
<head>
        <!-- Angular Js -->
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Application -->
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>

        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="app/controllers/pageController.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/dashboardController.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/departmentController.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/machineController.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/userController.js"></script>
</head>
```

When I debug the controller it doesn't get past the instantiation of the Controller on the second line. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: where are you declaring `dashboardController` ?

Comment: In the Head of my Index Page

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?  My gut tells me that the 'use strict'; is conflicting with the reference to app.controller.  I'm assuming that your controller is in a separate .js file (based on your snippets), in which case 'use strict'; MAY be freaking out as it doesn't know what app is.  (i.e. is the error something of the form "cannot call method 'controller' of undefined")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misspelled controller in your config. Also, as Nidhish points out, you can chain your configuration since the `when` call returns the routeprovider again.

So your (fixed) code is

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when("/dashboard", {
        // you have missed an r in controller here
        controller: "dashboardController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/dashboard.html",
    })

    $routeProvider.when("/machines", {
        controller: "machineController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/machines.html",
    })

    $routeProvider.when("/departments", {
        controller: "departmentController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/departments.html",
    })

    $routeProvider.when("/users", {
        controller: "userController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/users.html",
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/dashboard" });
});
```

and it can be rewritten to

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/dashboard", { controller: "dashboardController", templateUrl: "/app/views/dashboard.html" })
      .when("/machines", { controller: "machineController", templateUrl: "/app/views/machines.html" })
      .when("/departments", { controller: "departmentController", templateUrl: "/app/views/departments.html" })
      .when("/users", { controller: "userController", templateUrl: "/app/views/users.html" })
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/dashboard" });
});
```

Of course this is only personal preference, it does the same

Comment: Goodness me, I thought I'd triple checked everything like that. Thank you :)

Comment: The `r` word is hiding very carefully :D

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one

It simply a Spelling Mistake, instead of `controller` you have put `contoller` for dashboard

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6W5j2h0xMu3e3Aq06HvD?p=preview)**

```
 // create the module and name it app

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when("/dashboard", {
    contoller: "dashboardController",
    templateUrl: "app/views/dashboard.html",
  })

  .when("/machines", {
    controller: "machineController",
    templateUrl: "app/views/machines.html",
  })

  .when("/departments", {
    controller: "departmentController",
    templateUrl: "app/views/departments.html",
  })

  .when("/users", {
    controller: "userController",
    templateUrl: "app/views/users.html",
  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/dashboard"
  });
});


 // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

});

 // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('dashboardController', function($scope) {

});

 // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('machineController', function($scope) {

});

 // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('departmentController', function($scope) {

});

 // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('userController', function($scope) {

});
```

Comment: No joy, still the same :(